# Python Regex re.search - groupdict() - Date format matching

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the date month from various strings such as '14th oct', '14oct', '14.10', '14 10' and '14/10'. For these cases my below code working fine.

```
query = '14.oct'
print(re.search(r'(?P<date>\b\d{1,2})(?:\b|st|nd|rd|th)?(?:[\s\.\-/_\\,]*)(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})', query, re.I).groupdict())
```

Result:-

```
{'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
```

But for this case (1410), its still capturing the date and month. But I don't want that, since this will be another number format of that entire string and not to be considered as date and month. The result should be `None`.

How to change the search pattern for this? (with `groupdict()` only)

---

**Edited:-**

The mentioned parathesis in the number above `(1410)` is just to differentiate from other text. What I want to mean is `1410` only.

The below solution is what I want and I got the idea from the answer of @the-fourth-bird by adding `(?!\d{3,}\b)` in the regex pattern.

Thanks

**Final Solution**

```
import re
queries = ['14 10', '14.10', '1410', '14-10', '14/10', '14,10', '17800', '14th oct', '14thoct', '14th-oct', '14th/oct', '14-oct', '14.oct', '14oct']
max_indent = len(max(queries, key = len)) + 1

for query in queries:
    if resp := re.search(r'(?P<date>\b(?!\d{3,}\b)\d{1,2})(?:\b|st|[nr]d|th)?(?:[\s.-/_\\,-]*)(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})', query, re.I):
        print(f"{query:{max_indent}}- {resp.groupdict()}")
    else:
        print(f"{query:{max_indent}}- 'Not a date'")
```

Result:-

```
14 10    - {'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
14.10    - {'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
1410     - 'Not a date'
14-10    - {'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
14/10    - {'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
14,10    - {'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
17800    - 'Not a date'
14th oct - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
14thoct  - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
14th-oct - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
14th/oct - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
14-oct   - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
14.oct   - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
14oct    - {'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you don't want to match `1410` as in 4 digits only or `(1410)` with the parenthesis, but to exclude matching both you can make sure there are not 4 consecutive digits:

```
(?P<date>\b(?!\d{4}\b)\d{1,2})(?:st|[nr]d|th)?[\s./_\\,-]*(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT0Zvi/1)

To not match any date between parenthesis

```
\([^()]*\)|(?P<date>\b\d{1,2})(?:st|[nr]d|th)?[\s./_\\,-]*(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})
```

- `\([^()]*\)` Match from opening till closing parenthesis
- `|` Or
- `(?P<date>\b\d{1,2})` Match 1-2 digits
- `(?:st|[nr]d|th)?` Optionally match `st` `nd` `rd` `th`
- `[\s./_\\,-]*` Optionally repeat matching any of the listed
- `(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})` Match 1-2 digits or 3-9 chars a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Te0gPk/1)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"\([^()]*\)|(?P<date>\b\d{1,2})(?:st|[nr]d|th)?(?:[\s./_\\,-]*)(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})"
strings = ["14th oct", "14oct", "14.10", "14 10", "14/10", "1410", "(1410)"]

for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s, re.I)
    if m.group(1):
        print(m.groupdict())
    else:
        print(f"{s} --> Not valid")
```

Output

```
{'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
{'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
{'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
{'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
{'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
{'date': '14', 'month': '10'}
(1410) --> Not valid
```

Answer (score 1):

*How to change the search pattern for this?*

You might try using negative lookbehind assertion literal `(` combined with negative lookahead assertion literal `)` as follows

```
import re
query = '14.oct'
noquery = '(1410)'
print(re.search(r'(?<!\()(?P<date>\b\d{1,2})(?:\b|st|nd|rd|th)?(?:[\s\.\-/_\\,]*)(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})(?!\))', query, re.I).groupdict())
print(re.search(r'(?<!\()(?P<date>\b\d{1,2})(?:\b|st|nd|rd|th)?(?:[\s\.\-/_\\,]*)(?P<month>\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3,9})(?!\))', noquery, re.I))
```

output

```
{'date': '14', 'month': 'oct'}
None
```

Beware that it does prevent all bracketed forms, i.e. not only `(1410)` but also `(14 10)`, `(14/10)` and so on.